# addClass() successful, change not applied to page element

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day,

I have an html form that I would like to validate at specific times:

- on an input's `focusin()` event;
- on an an input's `focusout()` event;
- when the submit input is clicked;
- etc.

For example, I can add a CSS class, "selected", to an input when it fires a `focusIn()` event, but the input does not change visually to reflect the added class. I tested to see if the class was added and `hasClass("selected")` returns TRUE.

After a couple hours of trying different approaches and searching the Internet high and low, I can't figure it out why the class is added but the page doesn't change visually.

---

I don't think it's an issue with the way I import the css and javascript.

The style.css is imported in the head as follows:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">@import url("../css/style.css");</style>
```

The JQuery and script.js are imported in the head as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

[Here is a functioning codepen for the page.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXqOMe)

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing here showing the behavior, but if you're talking about the `.show` class in your CodePen, it's being overridden by the much-more-specific `.form1 p .invalid-message` rule, which specifies `display: none`

Comment: on focus , I am seeing left border is getting applied

Comment: @PaulRoub Ah, I didn't understand the precedence then. I thought by adding the .show class to the span it would just overwrite the "display: none" found in .form1 p .invalid-message. I guess I will change all my addClass() to css() to fix this.

Comment: @NagaSaiA That is the input[type="text"]:hover I think. If you move the mouse off the input that border will go away - at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option add more specific CSS for the .selected class

```
.form1 p input.selected {
    border-left-width: 8px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/borGvB

Comment: Glad my answer helped you :)